# Is there a way to use a observable returning function for each element of another observable array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

I get an `Observable<Group[]>` from my Firebase collection.
In this Group class is an id which I wanna use to retrieve another dataset array from Firebase, which would be messages for each unique group `Observable<Message[]>`.(each group has its own chat: `Message[]`)
And it want to return an observable which hold an array of a new Type:
`return { ...group, messages: Message[] } as GroupWithMessages`

the final goal should be `Observable<GroupWithMessages[]>`

```
getGroupWithChat(): Observable<GroupWithMessages[]> {
    const groupColl = this.getGroups(); // Observable<Group[]>

    const messages = groupColl.pipe(
      map(groups => {
        return groups.map(meet => {
          const messages = this.getMessagesFor(group.uid);
          return { messages:messages, ...group} as GroupWithMessages
        });
      })
    );

    return messages;

  }
}
```

and here the Message function

```
 getMessagesFor(id: string): Observable<Message[]> {
    return this.afs.collection<Message>(`meets/${id} /messages`).valueChanges();
}
```

sadly that doesnt work because when i create the new Obj I cannot bind `messages:messages` because messages ist vom typ `Observable<Message[]>`

I hope that cleares things

**UPDATE:**
my main problem now comes down to this:

```
getGroupsWithMessages() {
    this.getJoinedGroups()
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(groups =>
          from(groups).pipe(
            mergeMap(group => {
              return this.getMessagesFor(group.uid).pipe(
                map(messages => {
                  return { ...group, messages } as GroupIdMess;
                })
              );
            }),
            tap(x => console.log('reaching here: ', x)),
            toArray(),
            tap(x => console.log('not reaching here = completed: ', x))
          )
        ),
        tap(x => console.log('not reaching here: ', x))
      )
      .subscribe(x => console.log('not reaching here: ', x));
  }
```

when i call that function my console.log is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I follow what you're doing here but the logic look like you'd want:

```
getGroupWithChat() {
    return this.getGroups.pipe(map(groups=> {
        return groups.map(group => this.getMessagesFor(group.uid));
    })).subscribe(); // trigger "hot" observable
}
```

Let me know if I can help further after you clarify.

**UPDATE:**

So it looks like you need to get the UID of the group before making the call to get the GroupMessages[]?

1. get Group: Observable
2. call getMessagesFor(Group.uid)

this example gets groups result$ then
concatMap uses groups result$ to make the messages query

```
 this.getGroups().pipe(
     concatMap((group: Group) => this.getMessagesFor(group.uid))
 ).subscribe((messages: GroupWithMessages[]) => {
    console.log(messages); 
 });
```

You may still want to map them together but it seems like you know how to do that. `concatMap` waits for the first to finish, then makes the second call which you need.

Is this closer?

Comment: updated my Post i hope this makes it more understandable and readable, first time i postet something :)

Comment: this wont work since concatMap will create a ```Observable<ObservableMessages[]>>``` and this exactly is my main problem, the firebase call for each element in the group returns a single ```Observable<Message[]>```

Answer (score 0):

Use forkJoin to wait for messages to be received for all groups. Then map the result of forkJoin to an array of GroupWithMessages like this -

```
getGroupWithChat(): Observable<GroupWithMessages[]> {

    return this.getGroups()
               .pipe(
                 switchMap(groups => {
                   const messagesForAllGroups$ = groups.map(group => this.getMessagesFor(group.uid));
                   return forkJoin(messagesForAllGroups$)
                          .pipe(
                            map(joined => {

                              //joined has response like -
                              //[messagesArrayForGroup0, messagesArrayForGroup1, messagesArrayForGroup2....];

                              const messagesByGroup = Array<GroupWithMessages>();

                              groups.forEach((group, index) => {
                                //assuming that GroupWithMessages has group and messages properties.
                                const gm = new GroupWithMessages();
                                gm.group = group;
                                gm.messages = joined[index];
                                messagesByGroup.push(gm);
                              });

                              return messagesByGroup;
                            })
                          )
                 })
               )    

  }
```

Comment: @PhilippHumburg If it works then I would request to upvote [if you think to do so] it so that it can be helpful for someone else in the community for a similar problem. Thanks!

Comment: it seems newly joined members have their upvoted kept secret until a certain point

Comment: Ah! got it. Thanks!

Comment: ok it seems to not work for some reason, the typechecking gives the right arraytype back. When i subscribe to it, the subscription callback is never called

Comment: i used  ```tap(val => console.log('before forkjoin: ', val))``` to look into it and the forkJoin is never called, which is strange since the observable given into it has values

Comment: So in this code where did, you put tap - return this.getGroups()
               .pipe(
                 switchMap(groups => {
                   const messagesForAllGroups$ = groups.map(group => this.getMessagesFor(group.uid));
                   return forkJoin(messagesForAllGroups$)

Comment: after the forkJoin().pipe(
tap(),
...
) and this seems to get never called or reached

Comment: Can you do the following - use tap in this.getGroups() .pipe(tap(...), switchMap(...))? and see if your this.getGroups() is being called? this.getGroups() is your method which call backend to get the groups. I hope you must be subscribing on the return value of getGroupWithChat() method to invoke observable?

Comment: yep thats being working as expected, tapping into the groups works perfectly fine

Comment: When you say perfectly fine - means you received some values in “groups”? If so, then it requires to have more code to see the issue because for me forkJoin works fine. Although I don’t have similar setup as you have but basics are same.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do that by splitting `Observable<any[]>` to `Observable<any>` and then `mergeMap` the results to inner Observable.

Something like this should work:

```
  getMessagesFor(id: string): Observable<number> {
    return of(1);
  }

  getGroups(): Observable<string[]> {
    return of(["1", "2"]);
  }

  getGroupWithChat() {
    this.getGroups().pipe(
      mergeMap(groups => from(groups)), // Split the stream into individual group elements instead of an array
      mergeMap(group => {
        return this.getMessagesFor(group).pipe(
          map(messages => {
            return Object.assign(group, messages);
          })
        );
      })
    );
  }
```

Edit:

Consider BehaviorSubject. It doesn't complete at all:

```
const behSub: BehaviorSubject<number[]> = new BehaviorSubject([1, 2, 3]);

setTimeout(() => {
  behSub.next([4, 5, 6]);
}, 5000);

behSub
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(arr =>
      from(arr).pipe(
        tap(), // Do something with individual items, like mergeMap to messages
        toArray() // Go back to array
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(console.log, null, () => {
    console.log('Complete');
  });
```

Comment: that seems like its exactly what i needed, I`ll try that and post the result. thanks in advance.

Comment: that does exactly what i need, but it has the observable now splitted and I can no longer use it in an async pipe, since it is no longer an array. Any Tipps for that?

Comment: Oh, you can just `pipe(reduce)` the results back into the array.

Comment: `reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), [])`

Comment: hey that would work to some extend but the reduce would never know when to stop the listening for input, since it keeps getting single emits into it, so it will never complete.

Comment: But it will complete. Try it yourself. `const obs = from([1, 2, 3, 4]);

  obs.pipe(reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), [])).subscribe(console.log, null, () => {
   console.log('Complete');
  });`

Comment: Also I have just found out about `toArray` pipeable operator. You can just remove `reduce` thing and do `pipe(toArray())` instead.

Comment: I did exactly that yesterday aswell, but for some reason, the toArray() never finishes in my firebase example. Same goes for the reduce method. When i tap in to the reduce method, the elements getting reduced. But it never completes

Comment: the difference to your example and firebase is. the observable from firebase Collection never completes, thats the point of the real time databse, or am I missing something here?