# How can i fix the nested subscription to work sequential?

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators, rxjs-subscriptions

I am trying to subscribe multiple times to my own backend. While my code is fetching the data, something seems not to work right. By executing the following code everything is showed as it should be, except of the sequence. So my accounts are getting fetched in the correct sequence but my transactions are sometimes in the wrong order.

My code:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < this.userlength; i++) {

              //fetch transactions data of the account with index "countul" to our local storage
              this.getAccounts(this.as.getUserId(), countul)
              .pipe(map(accountData => {
                  return {
                    accounts2: accountData.accounts.map(account => {
                      return {
                        productDescription: account.productDescription,
                        balance: account.currentBalance,
                        iban: account.iban
                      };
                  })
                };
              })
              //If an error at requesting data from external bank occurs, delete every token 
              )
              .subscribe(transformedTransactionData => {

                this.accounts[countul] = transformedTransactionData.accounts2;


                      for(var j = 0; j < this.accounts[countul].length; j++) {

                          //Printing some things to the console for testing purpose
                          console.log("countacc: "+countacc);
                          console.log(this.accounts[countul][countacc].iban);

                          //fetch transactions data of the useraccount with index "countul" and subaccount with index "countacc" to our local storage
                          (this.getTransactions(this.transactionsPerPage, this.currentPage, this.accounts[countul][countacc].iban, countul, this.as.getUserId()))
                          .pipe(map(transactionData => {
                              return {
                                transactions2: transactionData.transactions.map(transaction => {
                                  return {
                                    date: transaction.bookingDate,
                                    receiver: transaction.counterPartyName,
                                    amount: transaction.amount,
                                    mandateReference: transaction.mandateReference,
                                    id: transaction.paymentIdentification,
                                    purpose: transaction.paymentReference
                                  };
                                })
                            };
                          }))
                          .subscribe(transformedTransactionData => {

                            this.transactions[countacc2] = transformedTransactionData.transactions2;

                            //Stop loading spinner
                            this.isLoading = false;

                            setTimeout(() => {}, 2000);
                            console.log("Transactions of account " +countacc2 + ": "+JSON.stringify(this.transactions[countacc2]));
                            console.log("Transactions of account " +countacc2 + ": "+JSON.stringify(this.transactions[countacc2]));
                            countacc2++;

                          }), error => {
                            console.log('There was an error getting data');
                            return Observable.throw(error);
                          };

                           //Go to the possible subaccount                            
                          countacc++;

                        }
                        //Go to the next bankaccount
                        countul++;

                      }), error => {
                        console.log('There was an error getting data');
                        return Observable.throw(error);
                      };    
            }  
      }
```

methods "getTransaction" and "getAccounts":

```
//Get account data of bankaccount with index (if there are more than one bank account integrated)
 getAccounts(userid: string, index: number) {

  //DataSchema for the http request
  const data = {userid, index};

  //Making a HTTP Request to our Backend with sending out userid and the index of the bankaccount we want
  return this.http.post<{message: string; accounts: any}>(this.apiUrl + "/get", data);

  } 


//Get transaction data of account with index of chosen bankaccount and the iban (if there is a subaccount)
getTransactions(transactionsPerPage: number, currentPage: number, iban: string, index:number, userid: string) {

  //Making a HTTP Request to our Backend with sending out iban of account, index of bakaccount and our userid
  return this.http.post<{transactions: any}>(this.apiUrl + "/transactions", {iban, index, userid});

}
```

So sometimes it looks like this:

**Account 1** - "first name" "second name" 
--Transactions of **account 2**--

**Account 2** - "first name" "second name" 
--Transactions of **account 1**--

I have to notice, that sometimes it is shown in the correct sequence.

May anyone help me to fix my code?

Comment: You shouldn't be nesting subscribes like that. Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550911/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-observable-returning-function-for-each-element-of-anothe/56558207?noredirect=1#comment99735484_56558207

Comment: @ritaj By using this solution, it would occur the same problem as using forkJoin.I still need the result data of my first subscription to make the request of my second subscription.

Comment: The question there uses `id` of the first subscription to get the second subscription parameter.

Comment: @ritaj Sadly, that did not help in the end. I tried it out, but the same error occurs :/

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the observables like this

```
let observable1 = this.http.get('apiURL1').map(res => res.json());
let observable2 = this.http.get('apiURL2').map(res => res.json());

Observable.forkJoin([observable1 , observable2 ]).subscribe(results => {
// results[0] is our observable1 
// results[1] is our observable2 
});
```

Comment: The problem there is, that i need the result data of my first subscription to make the request of my second subscription. Therefore, i can not make a forkJoin.